# Split PDF into Multiple Page Ranges with Multiple Outputs

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I need to split one PDF file into multiple PDFs, but using specific page ranges.

This [CPDF](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) command will split multiple page ranges, but merge them into a single PDF file.

```
cpdf in.pdf 1-3,90-97,112-end -o out.pdf
```

I need a command that will carry out a similar function to the above command, but output each page range to its own PDF.

I've looked for solutions to this problem in the PDFTK and CPDF documentation, but haven't found any help.

Comment: Just use a few commands if something is not achieved in a single run. In this case, you could have a separate command for each section, e.g. pdftk in.pdf cat 1-3 output out-1.pdf; pdftk in.pdf cat 90-97 output out-2.pdf  etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `cpdf` using a simple for-loop:

```
for pages in {1-3,90-97,112-end};do cpdf in.pdf $pages -o out-$pages.pdf;done
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to BeastOfCaerbannog’s answer above, you can also do this with Ghostscript. Just remember to quote your ranges if they are non-consecutive!

```
file=“some_file.pdf"; for pages in {1,2-4,”5,6-8",9,10}; do gs -q -dBATCH -sPageList="${pages}" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatabilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="${file%%.pdf}-${pages}.pdf" "${file}";done
```